# Custom Checkbox Styling - Label jumps on check/uncheck

Tags: html, css

I am styling a checkbox using CSS3. Everything works fine except that the label jumps whenever I check and uncheck the checkbox. Could you please tell me why?

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before{
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before{
  content: '\2713';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Check 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `overflow hidden` to your pseudo element to prevent the jumping effect. I also updated the css a little bit to compensate for the overflow and the fact that the arrow wasn't really centered properly in the box.

[JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pu48sdha/4/)

Here is my take on it:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before{
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 22px; /*Change width and height to compensate*/
  width: 22px; 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
  /*Added styles*/
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before{
  content: '\2713';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `position` for pseudo element to absolute and place it accordingly.

Here is a solution.

```css
div
{
  padding-left:20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before{
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before{
  content: '\2713';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Check 1</label>
</div>
```

There might be other attractive solutions too, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As reported by OP, there was(is?) a jumping behavior still present on demo. I added 2 more properties that might resolve the problem. I am getting the same desired results so I can't test it myself (hard to fix what you can't see).

**Additional CSS**

```
  margin: 0 5px -5px 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  position: relative; // This should keep the input positioned in one spot. 
  float: left; // This should keep any extra movements of label and/or input from jumping as well.
```

The point of adding these 2 properties is that both of them take the element(s) out of the normal *flow* of the document, therefore having little to no interaction with other elements that might normally nudge or displace inputs and/or labels.

---

- looked for that funky margin offset that'll always get added on in order to counteract that jumping behavior.
- balanced out the neg and pos values
- and added `line-height: 100%`

  `margin: 0 5px -5px 0;
    line-height: 100%;`

Also replaced the `div` with a `fieldset` it's not necessary, it just looks better. :)

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px -5px 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  content: '\2713';
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Check 1</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: if you check properly, the checkbox is jumping now

Comment: What are you using, I'm using Firefox and Chrome Windows PC

Comment: @takeradi Ok, take a look, and see now. I was getting a good result originally, but that doesn't mean that others are going to, so I added 2 more properties that might do the trick ;-)